# Move Show Applications menu to the top of the sidebar (dock) menu in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, appmenu, ubuntu-dock, dock

Right now I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and there is a Show Applications menu at the bottom of sidebar menu as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

In Magento 16.04, the Show Applications menu appears at the top of the sidebar menu and I want to make Ubuntu's menu appear in the same location,  just like the 16.04 version. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @JerareYoshi the solution is not working for me because its for 18.04 version

Comment: The command work for me in 18.04: gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true

Comment: @Shell Suite the above comments seems that's the right way. I doubt whether you installed `Dash to Dock` gnome shell extension or not. If not yet installed, install it and follow above commands.

Comment: @PRATAP You **do not** need to install Dash to Dock, those `gsettings` schemas and keys are already included. In fact there have been reported issues (e.g. two overlapping docks appearing simultaneously) after installing Dash to Dock over Ubuntu dock. You should not run both of them at once.

Comment: @Shell Suite I have run the command in terminal as suggested above and it worked in my Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: @JerareYoshi ohh yeah after i restart my pc it works